# ADFS, SharePoint On-prem

Tags: adfs, sharepoint-2016

We have a SharePoint 2016 farm with 8 servers. Also, the load balancer server is functioning to balance the request between the web-front-end server(s).  The web application is configured to use the ADFS as an additional authentication provider while the default is "Windows Authentication NTLM" also using at the same time in the default zone. As the web application has two authentication providers - ADFS and Windows - every time the user has to select the authentication method. If "Windows auth" is selected the user will enter his or her internal Active Directory account manually to login into and if the user selects ADFS, request go to ADFS and redirecte to Azure login as the relying party and a claim is configured. The ADFS thing is ok for me as it is working as expected.

But I want to resolve the intranet users in intranet network itself (Pass-Through Authentication). As we know ADFS has the capability to authenticate intranet users in company networks by setting up the ADFS property by Set-AdfsProperties -IntranetUseLocalClaimsProvider $true to have all intranet users use AD and not be redirected to Azure AD but somehow it's not affecting anything. The cmd is runing successfully but not working.

Is there any additional configuration related to ADFS or SharePoint which needs to be done to archive pass-through authentication or autologin for intranet users who have logged into the machine using AD accounts?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmLki.jpg)

Comment: Have you got IWA set up on your browsers?

Comment: Yes, I have deployed the GPO on the AD to have SP Site URL in internet explorer. All domain joined machines are able to autologin using windows logged in credential but still, provider selection page interrupting smooth authentication. 
Can we by-pass the provider selection page to archive the smooth login for intranet users?